# Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture in asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In my MVC application I have had the following line and it has worked fine.

```
if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == localizationItem.CultureInfo.Trim())
```

Now as I am porting my application over to .Net Core 1.1, it appears that *CurrentUICulture* has went missing in action.  Any ideas on what it's replacement is?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'Thread' does not contain a definition for
>   'CurrentUICulture' and no extension method 'CurrentUICulture'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'Thread' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   framework..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking to do localization.

Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization) on how you can do it

Once it's setup, you can use something like this to get the current culture for a user:

```
var rqf = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
var culture = rqf.RequestCulture.Culture;
```