# ASP.Net Core Multi Currency Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am converting an application from ASP.NET MVC to .NET Core where I used to handle currency types for different invoices.

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CustomCulture.GetCultureInfo(Invoice.Vendor.VendorCurrency);
```

`CustomCulture.GetCultureInfo(string CountryCode)` took the vendors currency and created a custom culture with some default formatting and the current currency type.

I have a model which has a currency type where we would pull the country code of the Vendor from the database and use that to set the currency type for the current view.

The same does not work for ASP.Net Core from my understanding as the views run on different threads.

Essentially it is the currency type which will change e.g. $ or R or €.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: Localisation will default the site to only one currency. I need to use multiple currencies no matter the location

Comment: check this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540599/thread-currentthread-currentuiculture-in-asp-net-core) hope this will helps

Comment: *Don't* use `CultureInfo` to guess the currency type, because that's what you'd be doing. Invoice currencies don't change, even if catalog prices are localized. Make the currency explicit. If you buy from Amazon UK the currency may match *your* culture (based on your preferred browser language) but the invoice will be in the *company's* currency.

Comment: Never mind multi-currency prices. When you book a ticket the price you see is most often *not* the currency used by the issuing airline. The *same* invoice may have different **amounts** in different currencies. To avoid legal and accounting trouble use a [Money type](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html) that combines a decimal amount *and* currency and prevents you from adding eg Dollars and Euros, or multiplying dollars with dollars. Explicitly save that currency near the amount in the database.

Comment: You may not have a choice in any case. Accounting rules may specify how currencies are handled. There may be only one currency per invoice line, or one currency per invoice, or you may need to keep multiple money amounts (value+currency) in the same line. The one thing you *can't* do is guess from the ambient culture

Comment: Multicurrency example. A Russian buying a ticket to India with an Indian airline, from a European travel agency. The display price will be in Rubles, the invoice in Euros while the *ticket's* price will be in Rupees. Never mind the credit card payments which could be in any three of those currencies.

Answer (score 3):

Handling currency in multi-culture environment is bit tricky. There are some valuable suggestions in comments; I will recommend go through them.

> The same does not work for ASP.Net Core from my understanding as the views run on different threads.

You are setting culture of *current thread only* using:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CustomCulture.GetCultureInfo(Invoice.Vendor.VendorCurrency);
```

When new thread is forked in your application, you have to set this again for it.

Instead, you can set the culture for any thread by default using [`DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture?view=netframework-4.8) and [`DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentuiculture?view=netframework-4.8) (at application startup) as below:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CustomCulture.GetCultureInfo(Invoice.Vendor.VendorCurrency);
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CustomCulture.GetCultureInfo(Invoice.Vendor.VendorCurrency);
```

I generally use following code (at application startup) which handles culture setting:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("MyCultureValue");
//Setup things here for `cultureInfo` like currency in your case....

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

Type type = typeof(CultureInfo);
type.InvokeMember("s_userDefaultCulture",
                    BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static,
                    null,
                    cultureInfo,
                    new object[] { cultureInfo });

type.InvokeMember("s_userDefaultUICulture",
                    BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static,
                    null,
                    cultureInfo,
                    new object[] { cultureInfo });
```

These properties are [available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to) in .NET Framework 4.5 onward and .NET Core 1.0 onward.

> In the .NET Framework 4 and previous versions, by default, the culture of all threads is set to the Windows system culture. For applications whose current culture differs from the default system culture, this behavior is often undesirable. In the .NET Framework 4.5, the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture property enables an application to define the default culture of all threads in an application domain.
>
> If you have not explicitly set the culture of any existing threads executing in an application domain, setting the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture property also changes the culture of these threads. However, if these threads execute in another application domain, their culture is defined by the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture property in that application domain or, if no default value is defined, by the default system culture. Because of this, we recommend that you always explicitly set the culture of your main application thread, and not rely on the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture property to define the culture of the main application thread.
>
> Unless it is set explicitly, the value of the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture property is null, and the culture of threads in an application domain that have not been assigned an explicit culture is defined by the default Windows system culture.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the wanted it culture which it looks like you have already then you could just use `string.Format` like this:

```
string.Format(Invoice.Vendor.VendorCurrency, "{0:C}", amount);
```

This will also allow you to specify different cultures in different places which could be advantageous in some situations.

Comment: Is there a way to inject this in the model to minimize recodeing on each view?